# powershell Internet Explorer select list

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer

I am using IE as GUI for powershell. This is quite fine, since we are using therefore only standard office tools. My powershell script opens a HTML page and waits in a loop for events. I am using two hidden fields, one provides an end criterium for the loop:

```
while ( $ExitLoop -eq $false ) {
$ExitLoop = $objIE.document.getElementById("ExitLoop").value
$Action = $objIE.document.getElementById("Action").value
```

The $Action now gets executed. In the form however I have also a list which I would like to populate from the powershell script. I initialise it :

```
<select name="Emails" width="60" STYLE="width: 60px" size="10" />
```

and I try to access it:

```
$EmailsList = $objIE.document.getElementById("Action ").value
```

but this does not work.Any idea, why ?And more important still, any idea how I can access this select list ?Thank you very much for any hint
Yours
Eryk

Answer (score 0):

Since Select is a Tag name, we can't use `GetElementById()` method.We have a method named `GetElementsByTagName()` for IE.Document Object.

you can explore that.

Regards,
Kvprasoon